# Get control ID of a page in global.asax that cause exception on Application_Error event

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, global-asax

I want to get the Id of that control which causes exception. Actually I am trying to convert a balank textbox into Int32 on click of a button and handling in my global.asax file to log exception details with textbox ID and button ID.Below is my code snippet to handle exception on global.asax on Error:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        Exception unhandledException = Server.GetLastError();
        HttpException httpException = unhandledException as HttpException;

        String ApplicationName = httpException.Source;


        if (httpException == null)
        {
            Exception innerException = unhandledException.InnerException;
            httpException = innerException as HttpException;
        }

        if (httpException != null)
        {
            HttpContext con = HttpContext.Current;
            con.Request.Url.ToString();
            Response.Write("Error on Page:" + con.Request.Url.ToString() + " On Event: " + con.CurrentHandler);

            int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
            switch (httpCode)
            {
                case (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                    Server.ClearError();
                    Response.Redirect("~/Home/Error/2");
                    break;

                default:
                    ////Common.LogError(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(), httpException, String.Empty, ApplicationSession.CurrentUser.FullName);
                    Server.ClearError();
                    //Response.Redirect("~/Home/Error/2");
                    break;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            ////Common.LogError(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(), unhandledException, String.Empty, ApplicationSession.CurrentUser.FullName);
            Server.ClearError();
            //Response.Redirect("~/Home/Error/2");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I Have invested a completed day to find it but unable to get my desired solution. Please help me ASAP. Thanks in Advance to everyone.

Comment: Is there anyone, help me Please.

Comment: Is there anyone who have more knowledge than me then reply?